# Akka.Remote config failures

Tags: c#, akka.net, akka.net-networking

I've been trying to create an actor system that uses Akka.Remote with akka.net 1.3... However, I can't create an instance of the system due to the following exception:

```
TypeLoadException: Cannot instantiate transport [Akka.Remote.Transport.DotNetty.DotNettyTransport]. It has no public constructor with [Akka.Actor.ActorSystem] and [Akka.Configuration.Config] parameters
```

The thing is, my config is copied from the Akka.NET documentation, and I don't know what I have failed to do.. here is the config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="akka" type="Akka.Configuration.Hocon.AkkaConfigurationSection, Akka" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <akka>
    <hocon>
      <![CDATA[
          akka {

            stdout-loglevel = INFO
            loglevel = INFO
            # this config section will be referenced as akka.actor
            actor {
              provider = remote
              debug {
                  receive = on
                  autoreceive = on
                  lifecycle = on
                  event-stream = on
                  unhandled = on
              }
            }
            # here we're configuring the Akka.Remote module
            remote {
              dot-netty.tcp {
                  transport-class = "Akka.Remote.Transport.DotNetty.DotNettyTransport,Akka.Remote"
                  #applied-adapters = []
                  transport-protocol = tcp
                  port = 9090
                  hostname = "127.0.0.1"
              }
            }
          }
      ]]>
    </hocon>
  </akka>

</configuration>
```

I would appreciate some feedback on what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

EDIT: here is the stacktrace:

"   at Akka.Remote.EndpointManager.get_Listens()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at Akka.Remote.EndpointManager.<>c__DisplayClass48_0.b__0()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()"

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have incorrect transport configuration .  instead of specifying transport you should use the default transport by removing

```
#transport-class = "Akka.Remote.Transport.DotNetty.DotNettyTransport,Akka.Remote"
```

the base configuration uses   Akka.Remote.Transport.DotNetty.TcpTransport,Akka.Remote  you don't need to explicitly define it in your  configuration , unless there is a reason for that.